# Flex: Get height of children...when to call function?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a function I wrote that gets the height of the application without scrolling. Meaning the height it would need to be to not have to scroll.

This is the function:

```
private function getContentHeight():Number
            {
                var height:Number = 0;
                for(var i:uint = 0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
                {
                    var d:DisplayObject = this.getChildAt(i) as DisplayObject;
                    //trace(d.name+":"+d.height);
                    height += d.height;
                }
                height += Number(this.getStyle('verticalGap'))*this.numChildren;
                height += Number(this.getStyle('paddingTop'));
                height += Number(this.getStyle('paddingBottom'));
                return height;
            }
```

This function works well but the problem is knowing when to call it. I planned on calling it after I add/remove any children from it. However thats still too soon because I don't get the correct height yet if I run it then. The fix I currently have is using a Timer to call the function about 300 milliseconds after a child is added/removed which seems to work well but I think this is a very risky fix. So I was wondering a better solution. I am thinking there has to be some sort of event I can listen for that will tell me when its ready for me to run this function, I just don't know what event that would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take a look at `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight` properties of `UIComponent` (so all the controls and containers have these properties), flex already measures required width/height of the containers.

Secondly, the right place to look at this properties are `creationComplete` and `updateComplete` events. In your case, if you add some children programmaticaly, you should handle `updateComplete` event after you've added you children.